# Assigning a discreet value to each row using IF/ELSE

Tags: python

I have a Python project which scores website users, the output is a floating point number between 0 and 1. For example:

```
   User      score
0  123       0.04355
1  456       0.01074
2  789       0.00000
3  987       0.00000
4  654       0.00000
```

I'd like to add a second column to my data with a discreet banding such as 'High', 'Medium' and 'Low' - what's the best way to do this in Python?

So far I have tried in `IF` statement, it doesn't work, but hopefully illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
if logreg_results.propensity >= 0.90:
    logreg_results.band = "High"
elif logreg_results.propensity < 0.90 >= 0.70:
    logreg_results.band = "Good"
elif logreg_results.propensity <0.70 >= 0.50:
    logreg_results.band = "fair"
```

Desired output:

```
   User      score       Banding
0  123       0.04355     High
1  456       0.01074     Good
2  789       0.00000     Poor
3  987       0.00000     Poor
4  654       0.00000     Poor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with parameter `right=False` for includes the rightmost edges:

```
bins = [-np.inf, .5, .7, .9, np.inf]
labels = ['Low', 'Fair', 'Good', 'High']
df['Banding'] = pd.cut(df['score'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
print (df)

   User   score Banding
0   123  0.7355    Good
1   456  0.6074    Fair
2   789  0.9000    High
3   987  0.5000    Fair
4   654  0.0000     Low
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue:

```
if logreg_results.propensity >= 0.90:
    logreg_results.band = "High"
elif logreg_results.propensity >= 0.70:
    logreg_results.band = "Good"
elif logreg_results.propensity >= 0.5:
    logreg_results.band = "fair"
```

If first clause fails, it certainly cannot be higher than `0.9` and so on.